# SublimeREPL : shortcut to pass R code with Sublime Text

Tags: r, sublimetext3, sublimetext

I'm looking for a shortcut in Sublime Text 3 for R syntax that have the same "behaviour" as <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>r</kbd> in the R app:

- Pass line if nothing is selected
- Pass only selection when something is selected
- Go to next line / end of selection juste after passing a line / selection

Any idea ? Is there something similar to NppToR for Notepad++ ?

Comment: I suggest using `SendText` package instead (there you can use `super+enter` (default) or set your own shortcut).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done using 'SendCode' package of Sublime Text. You can install it through Package Control. Just make sure that the R console is open before you use the shortcut (for me it's <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>r</kbd>)!.